# Filter logging from "cherrypy.access.173118160" where I need to have "cherrypy.access.*" for the logging option

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

How do I configure Python 3 logging to filter everything with a wildcard? cherrypy.access is using a random value or thread id such as "cherrypy.access.173118160" for each client connection.  Below is what I have that I have been trying to figure out how to filter "cherrypy.access.*" in "loggers", anybody know how to do this?

```
import os
import logging
import logging.config

def getLogger(name):

    if loggers.get(name):
        return loggers.get(name)

    logging.config.dictConfig({
        'version': 1,
        'disable_existing_loggers': False,
        'formatters': {
            'standard': {
                'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-11.11s] [%(name)s] [%(threadName)-12.12s] [%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
            }
        },
        'handlers': {
            'console': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard',
                'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
            },
            'rotateBytesFile': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
                'formatter': 'standard',
                'filename': '%s/%s' % (os.getcwd(), '/logs/example.log'),
                'maxBytes': 10485760,
                'backupCount': 10
            }
        },
        'loggers': {
            '': {
                'level': 'DEBUG',
                'handlers': ['console', 'rotateBytesFile'],
                'propagate': False
            },
            'cherrypy.access': {
                'level': 'WARNING',
                'handlers': ['console', 'rotateBytesFile'],
                'propagate': False
            },
        }
    })

    return logging.getLogger(name)
```

Comment: https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/basics.html#play-along-with-your-other-loggers

Comment: I didn't see anything in the link about how to filter all "cherrypy.access.*", this is still showing up in my console instead of just the file:

[cherrypy.access.184040880] [CP Server Th] [access:285] 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Jan/2020:06:17:49] "POST

Comment: I think you should set up just `'cherrypy.access'`, w/o that wildcard part. Also, this doc mentions how to disable access log screen output in the CherryPy's config.

Comment: Take into account that if something in your app configured logging before your invocation (maybe by calling the basic setup), you may need to reset root loggers.